# How do I install Flash?

Tags: firefox, flash

My friend has installed Ubuntu but I know nothing about the system and she is no longer around.

How do I install an application that would allow me to view things on Youtube,Netflix or things like tennis streaming on the net or in general viewing anything video wise? It keeps asking me for plug-ins and then won't let me to download anything. Also, can I download Microsoft Internet Explorer to replace Mozilla Firefox?

Any help would be appreciated.